Clear code and state query parameter of Auth0 callback in Angular with HashLocationStrategy
I'm using Angular v18 to develop a web application that will be deployed to GitLab pages. This requires me to use the HashLocationStrategy (withHashLocation()).
I also use Auth0 and can successfully sign into my web application. However, I notice that the URL in my browser keeps the code and state query parameters from Auth0 in the address and these parameters are displayed before the actual path:

http://localhost:4200/?code=myveryverylongcode&state=anencodedstatestring%3D%3D#/tasks

I tried to manually clear the query parameters but they are not even recognized:
console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams) prints just {} and this.router.navigate(['/tasks'], {queryParams: {}}) has no effect.
Auth0 is configured as follows:
provideAuth0({
      domain: environment.auth0domain,
      clientId: environment.auth0clientId,
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: environment.auth0redirectUri,
        audience: environment.auth0audience
      }, ...

with auth0redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/#/callback'
and gets called like this:
<button (click)="auth.loginWithRedirect()">

What am I missing here?

you don't have to use hashLocationStrategy: use this to rewrite urls to index.html
